# How can a custom IConnectionProvider be "injected" with required dependencies?

Tags: nhibernate

Trying to use dependency injection with custom NHibernate implementation classes, specifically an `IConnectionProvider`. The issue is that I need my implementation of `IConnectionProvider` to use some dependency components ("services" in the .Net DI terminology). If the provider were managed by the DI container, I would just make the dependencies constructor args and be done.

For example:

```
public class MyConnectionProvider : ConnectionProvider  {

    public MyConnectionProvider(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB) {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }

    public override DbConnection GetConnection() {
        // Use serviceA and serviceB to return a DbConnection...
    }
}
```

But the mechanism by which NHibernate instantiates things like IConnectionProvider is reflection, not DI-aware. How can I make a custom impl like this, which requires cooperating services that are managed by the DI container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to implement the NHibernate interface [`IObjectsFactory`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Bytecode/IObjectsFactory.cs) There are some DI-aware implementations of that for Autofac, Spring, and Castle Windsor (discussed [here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/05/nhibernate-ioc-integration.html) and [here](https://www.chadly.net/dependency-injection-with-nhibernate-and-autofac/)). I ended up writing an implementation for Microsoft default DI that looks like this

```csharp
public class MicrosoftDIObjectsFactory : IObjectsFactory
{
    private Lazy<IServiceProvider> sp;

    public MicrosoftDIObjectsFactory(Func<IServiceProvider> serviceProviderProvider)
    {
        sp = new Lazy<IServiceProvider>(serviceProviderProvider);
    }

    public object CreateInstance(Type type)
    {
        object instance = sp.Value.GetService(type);
        if (instance != null) { return instance; }

        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

It would be pretty easy to add a cache of un-resolvable types to help performance (avoid repeated lookups in the `IServiceProvider`).

To set this up, during `IServiceCollection` initialization, I use code like this:

```
Environment.ObjectsFactory = new MicrosoftDIObjectsFactory(services.BuildServiceProvider)
```

Comment: does this not leak memory? The root service provider shouldn't be used to resolve disposables (NHibernate will use this to get SqlConnection and SqlCommand for instance).

Comment: I haven't worked in .Net in a couple of years so I can't say for sure. What I can say is that this solution was used in a very large microservices platform in production without any reports of memory consumption problems.